# Merging data frame values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I would like to merge 2 data frames made from overlapping, but separate tsv files. FileA is a master list, and FileB contains a portion of the master list, but with many updated proofread fields. The goal is to update fields in FileA where file B differs.
Sample data:

```
filea <-data.frame('ID'=c('555555','66532','333221','333333','545678'),
  'color'=c('red','blaackk','green','green','oops'),
       'count'=c(1,2,300,4,1))

fileb <- data.frame('ID'=c('555555','66532','333221','444333'),
              'color'=c('red','black','green','green'),
                    'count'=c(1,2,3,4))
```

output should have "blaackk" corrected to "black" for 55532, but "oops" should remain as it's not in fileB. Count "300" should be "3".

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a good use case for `coalesce` which prioritize value selection from vectors according to the order passed to it. You can join the two tables by the `ID` column, and use `coalesce()` function to select color and count column from `fileb` unless the corresponding records don't exist:

```
library(dplyr)
filea %>% 
    left_join(fileb, by = "ID") %>% 
    mutate(color = coalesce(color.y, color.x), 
           count = coalesce(count.y, count.x)) %>% 
    select(-matches("\\.[xy]"))

#      ID color count
#1 555555   red     1
#2  66532 black     2
#3 333221 green     3
#4 333333 green     4
#5 545678  oops     1
```

---

Or probably a more efficient way is to use `data.table` package:

```
setDT(filea)
setDT(fileb)
filea

#       ID   color count
#1: 555555     red     1
#2:  66532 blaackk     2
#3: 333221   green   300
#4: 333333   green     4
#5: 545678    oops     1

filea[fileb, `:=`(count = i.count, color = i.color), on = "ID"][]

#       ID color count
#1: 555555   red     1
#2:  66532 black     2
#3: 333221 green     3
#4: 333333 green     4
#5: 545678  oops     1
```

---

*Data*:

```
filea <-data.frame('ID'=c('555555','66532','333221','333333','545678'),
                   'color'=c('red','blaackk','green','green','oops'),
                   'count'=c(1,2,300,4,1), stringsAsFactors = F)

fileb <- data.frame('ID'=c('555555','66532','333221','444333'),
                    'color'=c('red','black','green','green'),
                    'count'=c(1,2,3,4), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `match`, which is used to return the row indices of the replacement rows as well as the replacing rows.

```
filea[!is.na(match(filea$ID, fileb$ID)), names(filea)[-1]] <-
fileb[!is.na(match(fileb$ID, filea$ID)), names(fileb)[-1]]

filea
      ID color count
1 555555   red     1
2  66532 black     2
3 333221 green     3
4 333333 green     4
5 545678  oops     1
```

For brevity, I used `names(filea)[-1]` for example, to return the columns of the data.frame that are involved in the replacement, but you may want to instead use the actual vector of names as in `c("color", "count")`. This is more specific and allows you to specify the order or a particular subset of the columns in case they are not aligned across data.frames or there are some in one data.frame that are not in the other. There are two cautionary notes.

1. Any non-matches must be discarded the `!is.na`
2. The data.frames cannot have factors. Below, I read them in as character vectors using stringsAsFactors=FALSE

**data**

```
filea <-data.frame('ID'=c('555555','66532','333221','333333','545678'),
                   'color'=c('red','blaackk','green','green','oops'),
                   'count'=c(1,2,300,4,1), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

fileb <- data.frame('ID'=c('555555','66532','333221','444333'),
                    'color'=c('red','black','green','green'),
                    'count'=c(1,2,3,4), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```